# praise data from an attribute

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

want to get value of "data-defaultasin" attribute ,in b,c,d columns and so on from these elements (screenshot given).

product url- https://www.amazon.in/dp/B06XTB2N7P

[inspect ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbjhU.jpg)   [product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imvJ9.jpg) [worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVfxw.jpg)

```
  Sub praseasin()
 Dim ASIN

 Dim doc As HTMLDocument
 Dim htmTable As HTMLTable
 Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Dim img As HTMLDocument
 Dim i, lastRow As Long
 lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 For i = 3 To lastRow
     Set doc = New HTMLDocument
     With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
         .Open "GET", ws.Cells(i, 1), True
         .send
         Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readyState = 4
         Dim resp
         resp = .responseText
         .abort
     End With
    ' On Error Resume Next
     doc.body.innerHTML = resp
          Set ASIN = doc.getelementsbyclassname("swatchAvailable")

    ' On Error Resume Next
     r.Offset(0, 1).Value = li.getAttribute("data-defaultasin")
 Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you use `lastRow` and `i` variables. You loop is pointless since you overwrite the same cell, offset from `r` which is a variable you don't have declared anywhere... Maybe a visual representation of your desired end result would help? I assume that column A holds all relevant URL strings?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to get the asins from the different colors and put them in different columns. It's a demo script in which I've used one link multiple times. Modify it to suit your need. Thanks.

```
Sub FetchAsin()
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument, I&, R&, C&
    Dim linkList As Variant, link As Variant

    linkList = Array( _
        "https://www.amazon.in/dp/B06XTB2N7P", _
        "https://www.amazon.in/dp/B06XTB2N7P", _
        "https://www.amazon.in/dp/B06XTB2N7P" _
    )

    For Each link In linkList
        With Http
            .Open "GET", link, False
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        With Html.querySelectorAll("[class^='swatch'][data-defaultAsin]")
            For I = 0 To .Length - 1
                C = C + 1: Cells(R + 1, C) = .Item(I).getAttribute("data-defaultAsin")
            Next I
            C = 0: R = R + 1
        End With
    Next link
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft XML, v6.0
```

Comment: thanx for your help i appreciate it but i cant use id to praise data because it changes in every link only the classname is same as you can see ininspect ss ,thats why i used that secondly i want asin only in output which is starting from BO i dont want to concatenate link with it so can you help in it @SIM

Comment: I rarely go for late binding, so I wasn't sure @QHarr. However, I switched it to early binding.

Comment: You are still auto-instantiating inside the loop. Safer and more efficient to set in a var called http outside loop Set http = New ..... and Dim without the New

Comment: Yeah, right you are but the problem is some bad habits are hard to shake off.

Comment: its good can i give asin only in input which is starting from BO not whole link bcz only asin value is changing in each link rest is same secondly i want to give asin in input from column A instead of direct asins @SIM

Comment: The question you asked in the first place has already been answered. If you have any new requirement, feel free to create a new post describing what you wanna achieve @Skill Development. Thanks.